# Curry function without partial application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am following a tutorial on firebase authentication in ReactJS. In the code, I stumbled across such function:

```
const byPropKey = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
    [propertyName]: value,
});
```

I suppose this function is used to set state of a React component. It is used like so:

```
<input
    value={username}
    onChange={event => this.setState(byPropKey('username', event.target.value))}
    type="text"
    placeholder="Full Name"
/>
```

I am a newcomer to React, JavaScript, ES6 and functional programming in general, so this confuses the hell out of me. I know that the double arrow notation indicates a curried function, which enables partial application of the function. In this case, however, I can not see how this gets used in such scenario.

Here is the tutorial I am referring to:
[tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/#react-firebase-sign-up)

Comment: I will answer this in 20 - 30 mins

Comment: This is just a simple analogy, byPropKey  returns a function that returns an object.And setState needs a function as a parameter that returns an object. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional programming. Or currying. VTC as unclear.

Comment: @JaredSmith the OP's code is a demonstration of a higher order function. Isn't that one of the foundations of functional programming?

Comment: @Mark_M Yes, although it's unclear if that's relevant here or what exactly the OP is confused about. I still don't see any relation to FP other than that very tenuous one. If you want to add the FP tag back, I won't remove it again, not worth fighting over.

Comment: Currying and partial application are [different concepts](https://medium.com/@iquardt/currying-the-underestimated-concept-in-javascript-c95d9a823fc6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not see how this gets used in such scenario.

The tutorial author is currying that function because `setState` [can take either an object or a function](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1#6cdc). A function gives you access to the previous state and props. [Here is a sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/21n627xqj).

In the example you provided, the tutorial author is not using the partial application, and thus not leveraging the access to previous state and props. So in this specific case, a non curried implementation (passing an object to setState) would do just fine.

However, if you were to add to this tutorial codebase, the future code might require `byPropKey` to access the prevState and props:

```
const byPropKey = (propertyName, value) => (prevState, props) => {
    //... do something with prevState and props

    return {
        [propertyName]: value,
    }
};
```

... which is probably why the tutorial author wrote the function curried.

Comment: This definitely does answer the question, but I am still somewhat confused. Firstly, how would I call this function? Secondly, why not use an uncurryed form instead? It only seems to add unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the double arrow. This just creates a function, not necessarily a curried or partial function.

For example:

```js
// just a function
let doSomething = () => console.log("did something")
//call it
doSomething()
```

You can return another function from a function (aka a [higher-order function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), which is what's going on in your example:

```js
// this will return the function () => console.log("said " + something)
let saySomething = (something) => () => console.log("said " + something)

// call the above function, which returns a different function
let sayHello = saySomething("Hello")

// now call that function
sayHello()
```

You can make partial functions with [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```js
function add(a, b) {console.log(a + b)}

let addFive =  add.bind(null, 5)

addFive(3)
addFive(10)
```

To take it one more step, you can make a generic function to add whatever:

```js
// just a regular function
let add = (a,b) => console.log(a + b)

// a function to create a partial of the above based on passed in argument
let addThis = (a) => add.bind(null, a)

// make an add-10 function
let addTen = addThis(10)

// call it
addTen(12)

// make an add-33 function
let add33 = addThis(33)

add33(100)
```

**EDIT: In response to the comments**

Curried functions are those the break down larger functions that take multiple arguments into smaller functions that take fewer or one argument.

For example this simple function:

```
let add = (a, b, c) => a + b + c
```

can be *curried* into three functions that each take a single argument like this:

```
let addCurried = (a) => (b) => (c) => a + b + c
```

You can call this with some or all the arguments to get the result or a partial:

```js
// non curried: F(a, b, c) -> sum
// curried: F():a -> (b -> (c -> sum)) 
let addCurried = (a) => (b) => (c) => a + b + c

// add everything
let total = addCurried(1)(2)(3) // -> 6

// make a partial
let addTwoAndThree = addCurried(2)(3)
// call it
let total2 = addTwoAndThree(100) //-> 105

console.log(total, total2)
```

It's hard to see given the definition of currying how a function that accepts two arguments and returns function the accepts none is considered currying that function.

Comment: I don't think there's any confusion about the concept of arrow functions on OPs end. It's definitely a curried function and he/she is aware of the syntax that entails when using arrow function.

Comment: @Andrew there's no curried function in the OP's code.

Comment: @JaredSmith Look carefully. It's two arrow functions in tandem. Use that syntax and try and `console.log`. something while only invoking it once. `d = () => () => console.log('d')`

Comment: @Andrew I think it's a semantic argument regarding the defining of curry. To me, your example is just a higher order function. Currying involves breaking down the arguments. See edit above.

Comment: @Mark_M Now that I think about it, I agree with you. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
byPropKey
```

function uses as helper to map state and returns result like:

```
{ "statePiceName": value }
```

to set your state.

Same behavior without this function:

```
{event => this.setState({ username: event.target.value })}
```

Also you can just `console.log(byPropKey('key', 'customValue'))` and see how its works.